# Prove recurrent formula $(n+2)\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln{(\sin{\frac{x}{2}})}\cos{(n+2)x}dx = n\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln{(\sin{\frac{x}{2}})}\cos{nx}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

As stated in the title, I want to prove the recurrent formula $$(n+2)\int_{0}^{\pi} (\ln{(\sin{\frac{x}{2}})})\cos{(n+2)x}dx = n\int_{0}^{\pi} (\ln{(\sin{\frac{x}{2})})}\cos{nx}dx$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 1$.

So far, I've tried partial integration, and I've managed to reduce the equality to $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \cot{\frac{x}{2}}\sin{(n+2)x}dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \cot{\frac{x}{2}}\sin{nx}dx.$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Also, wolframalpha prints out $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for any $n$ I plug in, which tells me that the equality almost definitely holds, but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: Not sure how much this moves us forward, but we can consider $\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos(n+2)x)dx - \int_0^\pi \ln(\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos nx )dx = \int_0^\pi \ln(\cos(n+2)x) - \ln(\cos nx) dx$.

Comment: For this I would try by induction on $n$; show it is true for $n=1$, then set $n=k+1$ and show it is true for any $k$.

Comment: I don't think $n=k+1$ would help because the recurrence relation makes steps by 2.

Comment: Do you mean if we let the LHS=$I_n$, you want to prove that $I_n=I_{n-2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success when I shifted strategies, to prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \cot{\frac{x}{2}}\sin{nx}dx$ has a constant value - this was much easier. We use the identity $\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) = 2\sin(\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2})$, and proceed by induction: \begin{eqnarray} \int_{0}^{\pi} (\cot{\frac{x}{2}}\sin{(n+1)x} - \cot{\frac{x}{2}}\sin{nx} )dx &=& 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\cot(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)dx\\ &=& 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)dx.\end{eqnarray}
Now we use the "evenness" of cosine to obtain $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(\frac{x}{2})\cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)dx$$

and finally we use the identity $\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = 
\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta))$ to obtain

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(n+1)x + \cos nxdx$$

and this integral is clearly $0$. Thus, each two successive terms of your integral (i.e., for successive values of $n$) have difference $0$, and so it follow by induction that they are all equal, for any $n$.

Comment: Oh you silly answerer.  The math is correct, calling the asker silly is not.  We all have questions about things other people see clearly, that is why we have each other.

Comment: It's okay, I don't mind.

Comment: @OscarLanzi My (not especially serious) point was that we were trying to evaluate these integrals directly - but this wasn't necessary.

Comment: When you used the product-to-sum rule, you mixed up $\cdot$ and $+$, so the last integral should be $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos{(n+1)x} + \cos{nx})dx$, but this is also trivially $0$, because for $n \geq 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\int_{t}^{t+2\pi} \cos{nx}dx=0$. Either way, I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: Oops :P Nice catch, and thank you!